Ostensive gestures that accompany deictic sentences (Lakoff)
[Disclaimer before the fecal-storm starts: this is a post for people who believe ostensive gestures are not extralinguistic phenomena but a part of grammar, hence subject to grammatical rules.]
George Lakoff (1984) makes two intriguing observations that I want to run by you guys to see what your intuitive take as native English speakers is. His first dataset concerns the following sentences, which he claims are tied to speech acts in which the Speaker wants to direct the attention of the Hearer to somewhere in particular, heavily relying on perceptual data.

(1a) There's the bell NOW ringing in the distance.
(1b) There goes the gong.
(1c) Now THERE's a real cup of coffee.
(1d) Here's Harry NOW knocking at the door

This is the thesis that really piqued my interest: the "perceptual" sentences in (1), when accompanied by an ostensive gesture, it is a finger pointing upwards, not downwards or in any other direction (p. 7).
He also says that the ostensive acts that can be superimposed on the utterance of deictic sentences more generally (like There's Harry or Here comes Aunt Sadie) can only involve "pointing" with the finger or head (p. 3). (I'm assuming he's referring to a nod of the head here, rather than, say, a bow, which do function linguistically in quite complex ways in South Asian languages like Japanese.)
Is this a more or less good description of English deixis? I'm sure there's bound to be some dialectal variation.

"Ostensive" is an obsolete word, now chiefly found in Scottish English, and meaning "ostentatious". Isn't the word you need rather "ostensible"?

@LPH Ostensive has a clear meaning in linguistics and communication theory, relating to ostension.

I'm not sure if this is on-topic (psychology SE might be an alternative place), but (and here I think I'm getting well away from academic linguistics) you can touch or point with a wide range of body parts to indicate particular things, depending on position (e.g. kicking something on the ground) and whether your hands are full (e.g. indicate with elbows). People without fingers or hands will use other methods. Other gestures include a waving or circular motion with the finger, hand, or arm to indicate "this place".

I don't think you need a gesture with any of these sentences. The object they refer to is something the listeners all recognize, it doesn't need to be pointed out. E.g. everyone heard the bell/gong, you're just acknowledging it explicitly.

@LPH Come on now LPH. Stop making stuff up.

I'd try this on Linguistics, despite the language specific requirement. Or repost this with a different title (deleting this post). Maybe "Finger gestures and grammar" would get you the necessary audience for a good answer.

@Araucaria-Him No luck for your allegations, this is nothing else but what can be read in the Shorter Oxford English Dictionary, 1993 edition;  this new meaning must be of very  recent origin.

@LPH That's rather surprising as the OED has it listed as a current word and as being steadily common since the 1930s.
